# How to Check Props of a button class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Goal**

I'm trying to edit existing reactjs code to add a  under an existing button.  The existing button in question is a Microphone (depicted below) that currently allows users to Mute and Unmute. (I added the text "Mute/Unmute" to the picture just to demonstrate where I'm trying to add this new text.  and it would have to be either "mute" or "unmute" depending on the current state.

There's already logic that changes the icon from  a regular microphone to one that has a line through it.  I can't say I understand how it works.

**Problem**

I'm not a react js programming and so I don't know how to access the properties /state of the existing AudioMutedButton.

**Base Class - AudioMuteButton.js**

As you can see below, the base class exports some state information include _audioMuted:

```
_setAudioMuted(audioMuted: boolean) {
    this.props.dispatch(muteLocal(audioMuted));
    console.log("this is setting the mute state")
}

function _mapStateToProps(state): Object {
    const _audioMuted = isLocalTrackMuted(state['features/base/tracks'], MEDIA_TYPE.AUDIO);
    const _disabled = state['features/base/config'].startSilent;

    return {
        _audioMuted,
        _disabled
    };
}
```

** Presentation Layer - AudioSettingsButton.js**

This file seems to contain the layer that displays the Audio button in question.

```
   import AudioMuteButton from '../AudioMuteButton';

     render() {
        const { isDisabled, onAudioOptionsClick, visible } = this.props;
        const settingsDisabled = !this.state.hasPermissions
            || isDisabled
            || !JitsiMeetJS.mediaDevices.isMultipleAudioInputSupported();

        return visible ? (
            <AudioSettingsPopup>
                <ToolboxButtonWithIcon
                    icon = { IconArrowDown }
                    iconDisabled = { settingsDisabled }
                    onIconClick = { onAudioOptionsClick }>
                    <AudioMuteButton />                        
                </ToolboxButtonWithIcon>
            </AudioSettingsPopup>
        ) : null;
    }
}
```

I changed this to include a new if statement and React.Fragment, like so:

```
render() {
    const { isDisabled, onAudioOptionsClick, visible } = this.props;
    const settingsDisabled = !this.state.hasPermissions
        || isDisabled
        || !JitsiMeetJS.mediaDevices.isMultipleAudioInputSupported();
    var message;
   console.log(this.props._audioMuted)

    if (this.props._audioMuted) {
           message = "muted"
    } else {
         message = "unmuted"
    }
    return visible ? (
        <AudioSettingsPopup>
            <ToolboxButtonWithIcon
                icon = { IconArrowDown }
                iconDisabled = { settingsDisabled }
                onIconClick = { onAudioOptionsClick }>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div><AudioMuteButton /></div>
                 render(<div>{message}</div>  )
                </React.Fragment>
            </ToolboxButtonWithIcon>
        </AudioSettingsPopup>
    ) : null;
}
```

**What the Button Looks like:**

The AudioSetttings Button is the little button with the down arrow / chevron beside the mic and not the mic itself.
The button I want to add text to is the main button - with the mic on it.

[image]

[image]

**Problem**

I don't get any errors, the props is showing up undefined in the console.
So I'm clearly not accessing the state properly.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: can you show what `AudioSettingsButton` looks like? You may need to introduce some new state but hard to say without seeing the whole component

Comment: @Anthony see my updated question.  EDIT 1 section

Comment: How do you toggle the display for the microphone button? (assuming you have a similar crossed out display like video)

Comment: @Anthony I'll have to dig a bit more. (this isn't my code).  I guess I thought that since I can see the details of the audio in the console log ... whether it's true /false I could just somehow use the "this" object in the current context to grab the state

Comment: @Anthony I've added some React Debug information in case it helps understand the object structure.  Basically when the _audioMuted prop is true, i want to show an "Unmute" div under the button and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the `audioMuted` prop. Now you need to make a handler for the state that provided `audioMuted` to your component. The handler can be something like:

```
const mutedHandler = () => {
  this.setState({audioMuted: !this.audioMuted})
}
```

and then you can add an `if` statement to check if `this.audioMuted` is `true` of `false`, for ex:

```
this.audioMuted ? <p>Unmute</p> : <p>mute</p>
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm trying to figure out how / where exactly to access the _audioMuted prop.  I need to find the method that is triggered when the Audio button is clicked... instead of changing the renderAudiobutton right?  Render is likely only called at the start to initially display it.  Do you know of an easy way (via the debugger for example ) to find the click handler?

Comment: you can trace back the origin of the `audioMuted` prop in your code. Usually the handler is within the same component that owns that state.

Comment: k I'll try to do a global search of audioMuted to see what I get

Comment: please check Edit 2 in my post

Answer (score -2):

Use ternary operator to check the status
{ this._renderAudioButton() == true ? true:false}

Comment: can you explain a little more?